# What is the default autowiring in spring?

Tags: spring, autowired

Looking at my web application, it looks like the default autowiring is by name.  I did not use the autowire keyword in any XML files, but it's still autowiring.  Based on [this link](http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html), it looks like no autowiring should happen in this case.

Why is this happening?  Can we set it at a global level somewhere in the project?

Comment: Answer to this is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665220/autowire-default-mode quection

Answer (score 3):

The default autowiring in spring is by type

Comment: Please see my answer.There is no autowiring by default

Answer (score 2):

As this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-in-xml/) describes

Default, no auto wiring, set it manually via “ref” attribute. In case of autodetect – If a default constructor is found, use “autowired by constructor”; Otherwise, use “autowire by type”.

Answer (score 0):

For xml based configuration, the default autowiring mode is - `'no'`
That means, we need to manually provide the reference of the required bean to be injected.

For java based configuration, using @Autowired annotation, the default autowiring mode is -  `'byType'`