# Spring ConflictingBeanDefinitionException conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I encounter same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015205/2-beans-with-same-but-different-package-how-to-autowire). I know how to solve this, but I don't know why this is happening.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665220/autowire-default-mode) mentioned, by default the spring injection is `by type`, not `by name`. That's why we can inject the implementation to the interface.

In my spring web application, I am injecting the corresponding interface, while resolving by type, it should find the exact concrete class, but I encounter exception `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException`:

```
interface A;
interface B;

Class com.level1.Child implements A;
Class com.level2.Child implements B;

@Autowired
private B b; // expecting com.level2.Child obviously!
```

How come? Any better way to solve this? This is very annoying, because I need to annotate `Qualifier` at a lot of variables, due to there are many same class name in different packages of my application.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about how the beans are instantiated in the app: with .xml | `@Component`s through package scan | as `@Bean`s ?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple beans are defined with the same name, then the one defined later will override the one defined earlier.

I advice you to rename your `Childs` into `ChildA` and `ChildB`.